# MSSQL. Проблемы с кодировкой при импорте xml

Tags: xml, sql-server, openxml

Всем доброго времени суток!

В MSSQL создал процедурку(Function1), которой подпихиваешь xml-контент, а она уже загоняет её в таблицу.

```
EXEC [master].[dbo].sp_xml_preparedocument @DocID OUTPUT, @xml

    SELECT * 
    FROM openxml(@DocID, 'bla/bla', 2)
```

На php вызываю эту процедурку.

```
$fileContent = file_get_contents(iconv('utf-8', 'cp1251', $fileName));

$data = Yii::app()->db->createCommand('EXEC Function1 :xml')->bindValue('xml', $fileContent)->queryRow();
```

Ну и получаю, собственно, такую ошибку:

`SQLSTATE[IMSSP]: An error occurred translating string for input param 1 to UCS-2`

Кто-нить сталкивался с подобной ошибкой?

Comment: Судя по тексту ошибки не может конвертировать содержимое файла указанного в `$fileName` в UCS-2 (UTF-16).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Добрый день.

1. Попробуйте отказаться вообще от этой жути sp_xml_preparedocument. Это так делали во времена MS SQL 2000. Сейчас с XML работают вот так (пришлось делать скрин, т.к. тэги в коде мешают вставить сюда):
   [image: Пример работы с Xml в MS SQL]
   или (если первая ссылка не откроется), то она же: [скрин на picshare](http://www.picshare.ru/view/7708133/)
2. У процедуры, которую вы вызываете с клиента, делаете параметр типа @NVarChar(Max).

---

Далее код, который не будет нормально выглядеть из-за тэгов. Нормальный вид - смотри вложение в виде снимка с экрана.

```
DECLARE
  @StringData   NVarChar(Max)   = N'<Root><Record Attribute1="Value1" Attribute2="2" Attribute3="2016-12-31"></Record></Root>',
  @XmlData      Xml             = N'
  <Root>
    <Record Attribute1="Value1.1" Attribute2="2" Attribute3="2016-12-31"/>
    <Record Attribute1="Value1.2" Attribute2="22" Attribute3="2016-10-20"/>
  </Root>',
  @XmlData2     Xml             = N'
  <Root>
    <Record>
      <Field1>Value1</Field1>
      <Field1>Value1+</Field1>
      <Field2 Sign="false">111</Field2>
      <Field2 Sign="true">999</Field2>
      <Field3 SubAttribute="18+">2016-12-31</Field3>
    </Record>
  </Root>'

DECLARE @Data Xml = @StringData -- даже необзательно использовать CAST(@StringData AS Xml)

SELECT -- Запрос 1
  [Attribute1]    = Data.Record.value('@Attribute1', 'NVarChar(100)'),
  [Attribute2]    = Data.Record.value('@Attribute2', 'Int'),
  [Attribute3]    = Data.Record.value('@Attribute3', 'Date') -- Здесь необязательно использовать [N] у атрибута (как правило N = 1)
FROM @Data.nodes('Root/Record') AS Data(Record)

SELECT -- Запрос 2: аналогично Запросу 1
  [Attribute1]    = Data.Record.value('@Attribute1[1]', 'NVarChar(100)'),
  [Attribute2]    = Data.Record.value('@Attribute2[1]', 'Int'),
  [Attribute3]    = Data.Record.value('@Attribute3[1]', 'Date')
FROM @XmlData.nodes('Root/Record') AS Data(Record)

SELECT -- Запрос 3 - данные из узлов
  [Attribute1]    = Data.Record.value('Field1[2]', 'NVarChar(100)'),      -- А для узлов [N] - номер узла удовлетворяющий условиям!
  [Attribute2]    = Data.Record.value('Field2[@Sign="true"][1]', 'Int'),  -- Здесь: дай первый узел, у которого есть атрибут Sign со значением true
  [Attribute3]    = Data.Record.value('Field3[1]', 'Date'),
  [SubAttribute3] = Data.Record.value('Field3[1]/@SubAttribute[1]', 'NVarChar(50)')
FROM @XmlData2.nodes('Root/Record') AS Data(Record)
```

Comment: И всё-таки вставьте код текстом. Если что, мы подправим.

Comment: Так поток из файла отправьте в параметр типа NVarChar!
Там же в вопросе, как я увидел:
createCommand('EXEC Function1 :xml')->bindValue('xml', $fileContent)

Просто будет как-то так:
createCommand('EXEC Function1 :Data')->bindValue('Data', $fileContent).

Есть предположение, что в параметр типа NVarChar(Max) содержимое из файла ляжет скорее всего хорошо, т.е. мне кажется, что тут проблема возникла из-за того, что компонент доступа, который вы в PHP используете, не смог положить в xml

Comment: Чтобы текст воспринимался как код, нужно четыре пробела в начале. Можно использовать специальную кнопку в интерфейсе с фигурными скобками: `{}`.

Comment: Ну, конечно же я пользовался кнопкой "{}".
А потом Ctrl+V.
Просто из-за наличия тэгов, как я подозреваю, вид ломался.
Сейчас смотрю - поправили

Comment: @V.G. надо сначала вставлять код, а потом выделять его и жать {}. Или просто заранее вставлять код с отступом в 4 пробела (или в 8, если внутри списка) - оттабулировав еще в студии